# Trying to find InvoiceStorage dependency for maven

Tags: java, maven, junit

Im following a tutorial that has a external class InvoiceStorage i think, im very noob at this, but java cannot resolve that InvoiceStorage symbol, so i think i need a dependency that is not shown in the tutorial

tutorial link:
https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/stubbing-and-mocking-with-mockito-2-and-junit

```java
package com.mokitoTutorial.app;

import com.clusterra.email.sender.EmailSender;


public class LateInvoiceNotifier {
    private final EmailSender emailSender;
    private final InvoiceStorage invoiceStorage;

    public LateInvoiceNotifier(final EmailSender emailSender, final InvoiceStorage invoiceStorage){
        this.emailSender = emailSender;
        this.invoiceStorage = invoiceStorage;
    }

    public void notifyIfLate(Customer customer)
    {
        if(invoiceStorage.hasOutstandingInvoice(customer)){
            emailSender.sendEmail(customer);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this article, the author has just provided an example about how to use mockito. You can see the below from the above article.

> In a real system, the InvoiceStorage class is actually a web service
>   that connects with an external legacy CRM system which is slow. A unit
>   test could never make use of such as web service.

The author is referring to a class called InvoiceStorage, it is for example. There is no dependency. You can follow the article and you can create your own class to test.

Comment: How do i am supose to follow the tutorial if i dont know what InvoiceStorage class is suppose to have? XD  like i said im very noob i need step by step explaination ahahaha Can you give some hint about what InvoiceStorage class should look like on the inside?

Comment: Yes, it is true that the author has not provided any github link for the code. However, if you want, you can create a simple Customer class and InvoiceStorage class by looking into the above code.